# Is the sky of Mars black (except its lower side toward the horizon)?

Tags: mars

The site of CNSA has not yet posted color pictures showing the sky of Mars so we can not know for sure the color of its lower side (that part close to the ground as looking toward the horizon). However, the upper part appears quite dark, much like the sky of the Earth photographed from a high altitude.

Could we expect a black martian upper sky when China publishes the color pictures taken by its rover?

[image: The "Zhurong" rover successfully rolled on the surface of Mars]

[The "Zhurong" rover successfully rolled on the surface of Mars. Release Date: May 22, 2021](http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/n6758823/n6758843/c6812047/content.html)

(Download the video if it does not load in the window of your browser.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Skyshot.jpg

Comment: All you can infer from the image visually is that the sky appears lighter closer to the horizon, which is a pretty normal situation even for pictures of the horizon taken at sea level on Earth.

Answer (score 4):

There are many rovers/landers that have taken pictures of the martian sky before. Generally, as raw images, the color of the sky is a dusty caramel color, [as shown here.](https://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Curiosity-Sol-1454-Murray-Buttes-pano-crop-6B_Ken-Kremer-.jpg)

Here is one from the InSight lander as well, [which shows more of a gradient.](https://ourplnt.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/InSight-sol-0001_idc_D000M0001_596622265EDR_F0000_0463M.jpg)

I predict the sky's color would look something like the second picture, [depending on how it's calibrated.](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/734852main_pia16800-946.jpg)